# How to move Win7Pro OEM from HDD to SSD?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, usb, ssd

This is probably a generic question, but I could not find my specific case anywhere.

I am using hp elitebook 2570p bought from a refurbisher (?). it does NOT have HP recovery manager installed and the one I tried downloading would not work - harddisk.dll was missing, I didn't bother to download it as I read somewhere it wouldn't do jack s**t.

I was unable to download win7pro iso from the Microsoft site because apparently my version is OEM or something like that (came up when I googled the error I received when trying to download iso file).

Now I don't know if I can somehow connect both ssd AND hdd at the same time. I don't have an usb to SATA adapter and I can't get one any time soon. 
I do have 4gb pendrive around somewhere that I heard could be useful for creating bootable usb device (but won't that cause some license problems? and where do I get the iso file?).

I don't need anything that is currently on this pc except for legal windows and maybe, if possible, installed drivers.
I did not get any software to help me from the ssd seller.
My version of windows is "OEM_COA_SLP".

Comment: You should download a [Windows 7 ISO](https://superuser.com/questions/78761/where-can-i-download-windows-7-legally-from-microsoft/1046062#1046062) and use key printed on the COA sticker to determine your license key.  [This](https://github.com/Superfly-Inc/ShowKeyPlus/releases) will also return the correct key.

Comment: Thank you for the responses. So if this is correct doing so without the sata>usb cable is impossible? i will try to get it

Comment: You don’t want anything from your current installation, so just pull the HDD, and install Windows on the SSD

Answer (score 0):

You need clonezilla-live (live-installed on a usb stick or burnt on a CD) and a USB HDD.

You do a first 'device to image' from current HDD to USB-HDD then you install the SSD and do a restore (on new SSD) from the USB-written image to actual drive.

I did it on my PC and worked.

If you can get a sata2usb adapter you can do a device-to-device clone directly on new SSD

Comment: This won't work because the OP only has a 4gb pendrive which isn't enough to clone a Windows partition. Also, he doesn't own a USB-SATA adapter.

Comment: Thanks for commenting. Mind you i only want windows 7, nothing else really, can skip the drivers part. in this case 4 gb is not enough? should i get 8 or 16?

Answer (score 0):

I really suggest that you wait until you have a USB backup disk.
You could then use
[AOMEI Backupper Freeware](https://www.backup-utility.com/) (or another utility) to :

- Backup your hard disk to an external disk
- Create the AOMEI boot on the pendrive (if the computer can boot from it)
- Replace the HDD by the SDD
- Boot using the pendrive
- Restore from the external disk to the SDD.

If you are really in a hurry and would like to take the risk of wasting your time, you may :

- Backup your drivers (this is never guaranteed to be complete and usable).
  See [Best Free Windows Driver Backup and Restore](https://www.techsupportalert.com/best-free-windows-driver-backup.htm).
- Replace the HDD by the SDD
- Install a new Windows 7
- If some drivers are missing, try to install them from the backup,
  or if problem from the manufacturer's website.

In any case, you always have the HDD as a fail-safe if this fails.