# Did have a risk of corruption to my disk when i migrate it

Tags: windows, ssd, migration, filesystem-corruption

I tried to copy my current disk SSHD 1 To onto a SSD 1 To. Both of them are configured in GPT. I do the first section of this site

https://www.partitionwizard.com/help/migrate-os-to-ssd-hd.html

Ather a little while, the PC needed to restart to finish the copying so I did that. They have windows update and the wizard partion is stuck at 0%. It is like that since 1h.

[image: 1]

So my question is if I stop the the process now they have a risk to corrupt my original disk or only the destination disk gonna be corrupt? In the second case I juste gonna clear it and restart and if you can tell me what to do to make it correctly that's gonna be helpful.

Comment: Did you choose the option of "I would like to **replace** my system disk with another hard disk" or the option of "I would like to **move** my operating system to another hard disk. And keep the original hard disk in my computer"? If this was the second option then your data is ok. In both cases, you have no choice but to stop it (if it doesn't advance after 1 hour) and hope for no damage.

Comment: I choose "I would like to move my operating system to another hard disk" so i push power button?

Comment: Wait a while, just in case, and if it is still stuck on 0% then do so - there is nothing else you can do. If you can, disconnect the SSD before reboot, to ensure you are booting from the HDD.

Comment: Ok my computer "reboot normaly" some program is missing but everything goes well. So can you help me to make my migration sucessfull?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since in MiniTool Partition Wizard you chose the option of
"I would like to move my operating system to another hard disk. And keep the original hard disk in my computer",
your data is safe and you may hit the power button.

For a safer way for doing the migration see
[my answer here](https://superuser.com/a/1323988/8672).

Comment: But now i need to solve my second purpose how to make a migration correctly?

Comment: I recommend using the procedure in the above link. You may find more procedures in [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/99211/free-way-to-clone-hdd-to-ssd).

Comment: If i copied the partition one by one this is the same as doing th migration option?

Comment: No, since you will be missing the boot code. You really need the entire disk copied exactly.

Comment: So the only thing i can do it's do it again and pray that gonna work?

Comment: And also 3 partition seem to be correctly copied.

Comment: Yes, that's usually the case with such operations.